# ApplescriptObjC - Reading contents of plain txt file from Finder and making that a list

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I am attempting to read the contents of a txt file (list of IP addresses) and then make a list from them to use in a shell script loop.  Seems to error on the "set Switches to paragraphs of (read POSIX file file path)" and I assume I need to reconstruct but I know Applescript and barely getting into ObjC so this one has me stumped....

I really want to change the first three lines to set filepath to choose file but I get the same error.

```
on theButtonChooseFile_(sender)
    set x to (system info)
    set theuser to short user name of x
    set filepath to "/Users/" & theuser & "/Desktop/switches.txt" as string -- Define path to file
    set listOfSwitches to {}
    set Switches to paragraphs of (read POSIX file filepath)
    repeat with nextLine in Switches
        if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
            copy nextLine to the end of listOfSwitches
        end if
    end repeat
end theButtonChooseFile_
```

Error:

> 2016-08-25 08:13:37.655 Cisco Configurator[67884:4593159] *** -[AppDelegate theButtonChooseFile:]: Can’t make current application into type file. (error -1700)

Answer (score 0):

The AppleScript `read` command accepts also POSIX paths and you can get the path to the desktop folder of the current user simply with

```
path to desktop
```

The entire handler can be written this way

```
on theButtonChooseFile_(sender)
    set desktopFolder to POSIX path of (path to desktop)
    set filepath to desktopFolder & "switches.txt"
    set Switches to paragraphs of (read filepath)

    set listOfSwitches to {}
    repeat with nextLine in Switches
        if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
            copy nextLine to the end of listOfSwitches
        end if
    end repeat
end theButtonChooseFile_
```

But consider than `listOfSwitches` is only accessible **in** the handler.

Comment: Thanks. It's ok that the lisofSwitches is isolated.  Everything that needs it will be within that handler.  I think I can use your logic to combine path and file even though I wanted the user to be able to choose the file, I can have them choose the containing folder and build the full path using set filepath.  I do believe the real answer is within NSString but I am not versed enough in ObjectiveC to get there yet.  Thanks again!!!!

Comment: If you use `choose folder` to select the folder you don't need the AppleScriptObj level, however if you use `NSOpenPanel` then you have Foundation objects and you have to coerce for example an `NSString` with `as text` to use it on the AppleScript level.